# Evitar que acordeon de Bootstrap cambie de tamaño

Tags: bootstrap, accordion

necesito ayuda con el acordeon de bootstrap, de alguna manera cuando cierro todos las opciones, este acordeon se retrae  cambiando su tamaño y posicionandose a la parte derecha de la pantalla, mi intencion es que por mas que cierre todas las secciones del acordeon, este no cambien su tamaño y se quede con la misma longitud. Intente eliminar algunas cosas pero no ocurre nada, el codigo de bt que estoy usando es este.

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                  <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                    <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                      Accordion Item #1
                    </button>
                  </h2>
                  <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                    <div class="accordion-body">
                      <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                  <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
                    <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                      Accordion Item #2
                    </button>
                  </h2>
                  <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                    <div class="accordion-body">
                      <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                  <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
                    <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                      Accordion Item #3
                    </button>
                  </h2>
                  <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                    <div class="accordion-body">
                      <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image: imagen de lista sin cambio de tamaño]

[image: imagen de menu con caqmbio de tamaño]

Comment: prueba aplicando la clase `w-100`.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/sizing/

Comment: El Accordion y el Carousel estan contenidos dentro de un
`<div class="container"> <div class="row">Carousel & Accordion</div></div>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap funciona con una cuadrícula de12 columnas, si quieres que algún elemento no cambie de tamaño puedes usar las clases `container` y sus derivados, `col` y sus derivados para definir el tamaño de los elementos.

Aquí use los elementos `container` al cual después le agregue un hijo `<div class="row"></div>` y dentro de ellos otros dos `div` que les asigne la clase `col-md-6` para que siempre tuvieran el mismo tamaño de seis columnas.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false">
                <div class="carousel-indicators">
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                <h5>First slide label</h5>
                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                <h5>Second slide label</h5>
                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                <h5>Third slide label</h5>
                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                </button>
                <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            Accordion Item #1
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                            <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                            Accordion Item #2
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                            <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                            Accordion Item #3
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                            <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Fuente](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/)